# SQL Developer debug and Oracle 9

Tags: debugging, oracle9i, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to debug directly using Oracle SQL Developer 3.

I connected to the Oracle 10g and everything is ok, but when I am trying to debug on the same schema but on the another server(Oracle 9i) - I've got error:

```
ORA-00600: ...: [15419], [severe error during PL/SQL execution], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-06544: PL/SQL: ...: [pbjopnc - failed to instantiate], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-06553: PLS-801: ... [pbjopnc - failed to instantiate]
ORA-06544: PL/SQL: ...: [78601], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-06553: PLS-801: ... [78601]
```

As I understand there is a problems with `DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP` pkg on Oracle 9.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: For ORA-600 errors you should use My Oracle Support (support.oracle.com), specifically the "ORA-600 error look-up tool".  There appear to be several related bugs and work-arounds there.